# smartGWT listGrid change checkBox to image

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, listgrid, smartgwt-pro

hi all i am using smartGWT 4 .
i want to change the listGrid checkBox to radio button image i used the following methods but non of them works  :

```
         listgrid.setBooleanTrueImage("radioSelect.png");
         listgrid.setBooleanFalseImage("radioDisSelect.png");
```

and

```
        listgrid.setCheckboxFieldTrueImage("radioSelect.png");
        listgrid.setCheckboxFieldFalseImage("radioDisSelect.png");
```

can any one please provide any help ?
in smartGWT 3 i used :

```
         listgrid.setBooleanTrueImage("radioSelect.png");
         listgrid.setBooleanFalseImage("radioDisSelect.png");
```

but now they are not worcking in smartGWT 4.

when i inspect the checkBox using inspect element i notice the  image URL in the css class
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why those ListGrid methods don't work, but I believe you can control those images (app-wide) via load_skin.js.  See isc.CheckboxItem --> checkedImage and uncheckedImage.